# Setting "All Mailboxes" default sort in search

Tags: macos, mail.app

When searching in Mail for macOS, it uses "All Mailboxes" as the default search location. This is a mailbox that only appears in the sidebar when searching.

For some reason, my default sort for this folder is "From" and I would like to switch it to "Date".  However, every time I set it, it reverts to "From" the next time I end up in "All Mailboxes".

After experimenting a bit, it looks like changes to sort are persisted for mailboxes is you change it when search is not active, but not if you change it when search is active.  Unfortunately, you can never set the "All Mailboxes" sort when search isn't active, because it's not in the list.

Is there any other way to set this default sort? I'm guessing the sort is somewhere in a preference file because "From" is a lousy default sort.

Comment: How do you set the default sort field to date (even though, in your case at least, it does not stick)?

Comment: @Alper I set the sort using View -> Sort By -> Date in the menu. It sorts the current list and it keeps that setting if not in search.  You used to be able to sort directly from the list.